# Saving multiple record from Qtable into Pickle

Tags: python, pyqt5, pickle, qtablewidget

[image]

```
def save():
    file=open("data1.pickle","wb")
    pickle.dump(table,file)
    file.close()
    print("data saved")
```

i want to save the records being displayed in the table into a pickle file, and when i click upload all the recrds should be displayed again. how am i supposed to do this? pls help.

Comment: Please add description what is happening now when you use this part of your code and what is desired behavior.

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to add the description. pls help me out if you know the answers! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the text values from the table rows and store it inside a `dict` with respect to their column header. You can then save the `dict` using pickle.

See the below example to know how I would save the table

```
import sys
import pickle, copy
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add new Row", clicked=self.addRow)
        self.delete_records = QtWidgets.QPushButton("delete Records", clicked=self.deleteRecords)
        self.save_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Save Records", clicked=self.serialize)
        self.load_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Upload Records", clicked=self.deserialize)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.btn)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.delete_records)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.save_btn)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.load_btn)

        self._dict = {"Name": [], "Roll No": [], "Gender": [], "class": [], "section": []}

        self.createTable()

    def createTable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self._dict.keys())

        self.layout().insertWidget(0, self.tableWidget)

    def deleteRecords(self):
        self.tableWidget.clearContents()

    def addRow(self):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())

    def getRowValues(self) -> dict:  # gets the row values

        ord_dict = copy.deepcopy(self._dict)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for index, column in enumerate(ord_dict.keys()):
                item = self.tableWidget.item(row, index)
                value = ""
                if item:
                    value = item.text()
                ord_dict[column].append(value)

        return ord_dict

    def serialize(self):
        val = self.getRowValues()
        with open('data1.pickle', 'wb') as write:
            pickle.dump(val, write)

    def deserialize(self):

        with open('data1.pickle', 'rb') as read:
            val = pickle.load(read)  # loads a dict

        self.tableWidget.deleteLater()  # removes the table
        self.createTable() # recreates the tables

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(list(val.values())[0]))  # sets the number of rows

        for column, lst in enumerate(val.values()):
            for row, x in enumerate(lst):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = App()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the above code, I have written `serialize` and `deserialize` methods to save and restore the table.

Before adding the values from the pickle file make sure to clear the table contents. In my code, I simply delete the table widget and add it again. You can also use the `QTableWidget.clearContents()`, but this will only remove the content inside the rows, not the row itself.

**Edit**:
I just realized that you could also use `self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)` instead of deleting and recreating the table.

So in my code you can replace this :

```
self.tableWidget.deleteLater()  # removes the table
self.createTable() # recreates the tables
```

with `self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)`